Do passkey's support privacy as well as security or just security?
Do passkey's support privacy as well as security or just security?
Can passkeys be used to identify individuals across websites against the user's wishes and subsequent configuration?

No, they cannot.

Passkeys primarily ensure security, but they also enhance privacy.
They do not inherently identify individuals across websites without user consent and proper configuration.
